# Would it be within SE's mission to have a site just for advice?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is a question and answer site first. According to several FAQ questions, this site is not chiefly for **individual help**, but for a **group archive of knowledge.** Therefore, it would be against this purpose to have an advice site.

However, in a different perspective, any advice(life advice, domain-related advice) does contribute to the overall knowledge of our community. I support the strong moderation of Stack Exchange because it keeps our community clear and clean, but it often also closes content that is personal to the writer. Is this necessarily the best way to do things? Could an advice community(for example, "SE careers") add to the community's overall knowledge and therefore be within our mission?

I'd love to discuss.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Downvoted because you haven't included any specific information in your complaint that could be used to guide you to the right site. Therefore, we can't really help you, and it's wasting our time.

Comment: A network (of sites?) or a site?

Comment: @200_success  I have edited this question: I was just a 7th grader when I wrote it, but I see now how it is unclear and I believe it merits further review.

Comment: your edit invalidated the current answer. That is frowned upon

Comment: @rene Okay, how should I edit the original question to be more clear while still keeping the cufrrent answer? It was an ill-thought-out question to begin with, so I'm not sure how to rectify the situation best. Appreciate your advice!

Comment: if there is an answer your edit options are limited. The current revision is for sure a duplicate so I won't advice to ask a new question. Accept there is a dead-lock here.

Comment: I pinged the OP of the answer in chat. Let's see what their opinion is.

Comment: Thank you! @rene I am currently in a question ban because of questions from two years ago, so I'm making an effort to improve my contributions to the site.

Comment: @user12390879 You should do that for the questions you have on the site you are q-banned from... You only have this one question here, and improving this one won't help on another site.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Thank you. Could I ask you to review my contributions to Stack Overflow? I believe I have improved my contributions, but my question ban is not lifted

Comment: @user12390879 I'd love to, but I have absolutely no knowledge of how that site is supposed to work. So I can't help, sorry! Good luck though :)

Answer (score 3):

We have such a site. This one, Meta Stack Exchange.

You have here the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag, and this is its excerpt:

> Don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site. Search on stackexchange.com before asking.

Comment: Now you have, it's not trivial but simple search should give you this info as well. :)